# MYSQL WORKBENCH: Separating last 2 characters from a column

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to remove the last two characters from a column. The current column that I am targeting has already been created by separating a string, but as you'll see below, it wasn't successful for the 'City' column.

This is how the original looks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAhbX.jpg)

This is what I've been able to output from my code:

```
| StreetNumber | Street          | **City**              | State       |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1808        | FOX CHASE DR    | **GOODLETTSVILLE TN** | TN          |
|  1832        | FOX CHASE DR    | **GOODLETTSVILLE TN** | TN          |
|  2005        | SADIE LN        | **GOODLETTSVILLE TN** | TN          |
```

actual pic:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phVOy.jpg)

This is my code:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(OwnerAddress, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as StreetNumber, 
       substring(OwnerAddress, locate(' ', OwnerAddress), 
                 (length(OwnerAddress) - (length(substring_index(OwnerAddress, ' ', 1)) 
                 + length(substring_index(OwnerAddress, ' ', -2))))) as Street,          
       substring(substring_index(OwnerAddress, ' ', -2) from 1 for length(OwnerAddress)-2) as City,         
       substring_index(OwnerAddress, ' ', -1) as State
from nashhousing;
```

The goal is to remove the state abbreviations from the 'City' column because there's a state column already. I thought I could simply -2 for the last two characters but obviously, that didn't work. I hope I've explained my situation clearly, but if not, please let me know. I don't want to give up on this situation but I've been on it for 5 hours already and can't source a solution. Please help and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you are using the wrong field and value for the length portion of the `SUBSTRING` on the city field.

This should correct your issue:

```
substring(substring_index(OwnerAddress, ' ', -2), 1, substring_index(OwnerAddress, ' ', -2) - 2) as City,
```

Or even

```
substring_index(substring_index(OwnerAddress, ' ', -2), ' ', 1) as City
```

**Please Note:**

The major issue with doing things this way is you are assuming every entry is formatted the same, and you're not taking into account cities with two names. ie New York City, Los Angeles, San Francisco, etc.

This is something that you likely need to parse outside of MySQL. Since you only need it to be parsed, you could likely write a decent enough RegEx to handle the majority of the cases. However, if accuracy is your top priority, I would recommend geocoding the data.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have tried both lines, but they output an empty City column. I might just update the table and run another statement to remove the state abbreviations. What do you think? Also, thank you for the advice about geocoding. I will have to look into it more.

Comment: I'm not sure how either of those statements could return an empty string unless the field itself was empty. `SELECT substring_index(substring_index(OwnerAddress, ' ', -2), ' ', 1) as City
FROM (
 SELECT '1808 FOX CHASE DR GOODLETTSVILLE TN' OwnerAddress
) x` returns `GOODLETTSVILLE`

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. There are some empty fields for this column, 30 if I recall, out of 5,800, but I don't think that would cause the entire column to be empty. So, just to be able to move forward; I trimmed away the last two characters with a different syntax, and now the state abbreviations are gone. Thanks again, Marshall, for your time and advice!